# Using a crontab to gzip a file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I need to make a crontab to gzip a file named `mh` located on my desktop every 2 minutes in the same path. I tried

```
2 * * * * gzip home/Desktop/mh >> home/Desktop
```

But it is not working, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try using an absolute path to your script. like /home/user/.../mh instead of home/Desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors here.

1. The gzip command should be simply `gzip home/Desktop/mh`.  Remove the `>>` and everything afterwards.
2. Your current cron will only run on the second minute of every hour.  Instead you want `*/30 * * * * ...` to run 30 times per hour.

Note that `gzip` is "destructive" in the sense that your original file (`mh`) will disappear after each `gzip`.  That would be bad if some other process is trying to write to it continually...

If you want to keep the content of `mh` and just update `mh.gz` from it periodically, you want to do

```
*/30 * * * * gzip < /home/Desktop/mh > /home/Desktop/mh.gz
```

Comment: Ok, my answer seems to be going through some edit craziness, so I will just correct myself here:  you actually want `*/2` in the minutes column to run every 2 minutes (not `*/30` as I originally wrote).  Sorry about that.